# Incorrect signature on Rest api unittest

Tags: apex, unit-test, rest-api, webservices, json

I have made a (POST) webservice. I am trying to write a unittest but keep getting the error incorrect signature: void createInvoice() from the type InvoiceManager before I can save my class, what am i missing?

Webservice:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/invoices/*')
global with sharing class InvoiceManager {
   @HttpPost
    global static ID createInvoice (
        String customerId,
        String addressId,
        String invoiceId,
        String invoiceType,
        String invoiceTypeLocalized,
        String invoiceDate,
        String paymentDueDate,
        String invoiceNumber,
        String startDate,
        String endDate,
        String periodDescription,
        Double amount,
        Double vatAmount,
        Double totalAmount 
    ) {
        invoice__c thisinvoice = new invoice__c (
            customerId__c = customerId,
            addressId__c = addressId,
            invoiceId__c = invoiceId,
            invoiceType__c = invoiceType,
            invoiceTypeLocalized__c = invoiceTypeLocalized,
            invoiceDate__c = Date.valueOf(invoiceDate.replace('T',' ')),
            paymentDueDate__c = Date.valueOf(paymentDueDate.replace('T',' ')),
            invoiceNumber__c = invoiceNumber,
            startDate__c = Date.valueOf(startDate.replace('T',' ')),
            endDate__c = Date.valueOf(endDate.replace('T',' ')),
            periodDescription__c = periodDescription,
            amount__c = amount,
            vatAmount__c = vatAmount,
            totalAmount__c = totalAmount
        );
        insert thisInvoice;
        return thisInvoice.Id;
    }   
}
```

Unittest:

```
    static testMethod void  testPostRestService(){

        String customerId;
        String addressId;
        String invoiceId;
        String invoiceType;
        String invoiceTypeLocalized;
        String invoiceDate ='2015-02-13T00:00:00' ;
        String paymentDueDate ='2015-02-20T00:00:00' ;
        String invoiceNumber;
        String startDate ='2015-01-01T00:00:00';
        String endDate ='2020-01-01T00:00:00';
        String periodDescription;
        Double amount;
        Double vatAmount;
        Double totalAmount; 

        invoice__c thisinvoice = new invoice__c (
            customerId__c = customerId,
            addressId__c = addressId,
            invoiceId__c = invoiceId,
            invoiceType__c = invoiceType,
            invoiceTypeLocalized__c = invoiceTypeLocalized,
            invoiceDate__c = Date.valueOf(invoiceDate.replace('T',' ')),
            paymentDueDate__c = Date.valueOf(paymentDueDate.replace('T',' ')),
            invoiceNumber__c = invoiceNumber,
            startDate__c = Date.valueOf(startDate.replace('T',' ')),
            endDate__c = Date.valueOf(endDate.replace('T',' ')),
            periodDescription__c = periodDescription,
            amount__c = amount,
            vatAmount__c = vatAmount,
            totalAmount__c = totalAmount
        );
        insert thisInvoice;

        String JsonMsg=JSON.serialize(thisInvoice);

        Test.startTest();
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

        req.requestUri = 'https://eu10.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/invoices/';   //Request URL
        req.httpMethod = 'POST';//HTTP Request Type
        req.requestBody = Blob.valueof(JSONMsg);

        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response= res;

        InvoiceManager.createInvoice('1','8212BJ154','70ec3a54a43d014aa9e8','AdvancePayment','Voorschot','2015-02-13T00:00:00','2015-02-20T00:00:00','157005888','2015-03-01T00:00:00','2015-04-01T00:00:00','Maart 2015',165.29,34.71,200.00);
        Test.StopTest(); 

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Part 1: Calling Static Methods

In unit tests, you don't test RestResource by calling it like a regular rest call, but instead call your code directly, just as if it were any other method. Your unit test would look more like this:

```
InvoiceManager.createInvoice('value a','value b','value c', ...);
```

You can read more about how to call methods in the [Class Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining_methods.htm) documentation.

---

## Part 2: Decimal vs Double

In your method, you specified the Double data type, but in your unit test, you're using the default Decimal data type. For some reason, the compiler won't allow you to pass in Decimal values, so you need to either change the parameter type to Decimal, or specify Double numbers:

```
InvoiceManager.createInvoice(
  '1', '8212BJ154', '70ec3a54a43d014aa9e8', 'AdvancePayment', 'Voorschot',
  '2015-02-13T00:00:00','2015-02-20T00:00:00','157005888',
  '2015-03-01T00:00:00','2015-04-01T00:00:00','Maart 2015',
   165.29d, 34.71d, 200.00d);
```

The suffix `d` specifies that this is a smaller Double value, not a Decimal value.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit further I edited mu unittest but still get same error

Comment: @Thomas No, you don't pass in the JSON string, you pass in each parameter individually.

Comment: I cant find an example so is this like  InvoiceManager.createInvoice(customerId='1' , addressId ='acb',...??

Comment: @Thomas No, just like calling a normal function: `InvoiceManager.createInvoice('1','abc',...)`

Comment: This is killing me I updated the tesclass but still get : Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void createInvoice(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, Decimal, Decimal, Decimal) from the type InvoiceManager

Comment: @Thomas You used Double in your method, but Decimal values in your unit test. You can't freely convert Decimal to a Double, you have to either specify the Double value, downcast from Decimal, or change your parameters to use Decimal. One sec and I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks! I just figured this out also, what a bummer.